# Move data into a viewmodel using javascript/razor from within the view

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

How can I move data into a viewmodel using javascript/razor from within the view. my viewmodel contains:
public ListAttachmentList { get; set; }
which I want to use to store selected files, the files can be in different folders,  (from

```
        $('input[type=file]').on("change", function (e) {
        //add <li> entry under <ul id="AttachedFiles"...
        for (var i = 0, l = this.files.length; i < l; i++) {
            $("#AttachedFiles").append('<li id="li' + String(i) + '" style="margin-left:20px;"><input type="button" id="btn' + String(i) + '" value="Del" style="margin-right:10px;" />' + this.files[i].name + '</li>');
            registerRemoveFileEvents();
            myFile = this.files[i]
            myFileLst.push(myFile);
        }

        @Model.AttachmentList = myFileLst
    });
```

this all works fine except for the last line @Model.AttachmentList = myFileLst. So the question is how do I move data back into the viewmodel so it will be available in the controller? Or is this not the right approach?

Comment: public ListAttachmentList { get; set; } should read  public List<HttpPostedFileBase>AttachmentList { get; set; }

Comment: It isn't the right approach. You're Model is something server sided. Javascript is execute on the client. You'll have to make a new HTTP call to your server to provide the data you want to add. I believe this is a to broad question to answer here, but someone might disagree.

Comment: The data is collected on the client-side the question is how should the data be returned to the controller.

Comment: Do a new HTTP request with the data.
www.mywebsite.com/MyController/SetMyData?data=???